# How to append randomly generated values to a list if you're running the function multiple times?

Tags: python, list, random

What I want this code (shown below) to do is print out 10 random float values and after the 10th term it prints out the actual random number and adds it to a list. If the user then decides to run the function again I want those two (or more) values added within the list (add_rand_num = []). How would I go about doing this?

```
import random
import time

def randnum():
    num = random.uniform(.0005, .5)
    add_rand_num = []
    for x in range(10):
        print(random.uniform(.0005, .5))
        time.sleep(.5)
    print("----------------------")
    print(num)
    add_rand_num.append(num)
    while True:
        redo = input("Would you like to generate another num? Enter Y for YES or N for NO: ")
        if redo == "Y":
            randnum()
            break
        elif redo == "N":
            print(f"The sum of the numbers you generated is {add_rand_num}! ")
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either Y for YES or N for NO")

randnum()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can restructure the code as below to get result as expected

```
    add_rand_num = []
    while True:
        num = random.uniform(.0005, .5)
        for x in range(10):
            print(random.uniform(.0005, .5))
            time.sleep(.5)
        print("----------------------")
        print(num)
        add_rand_num.append(num)
        redo = input("Would you like to generate another num? Enter Y for YES or N for NO: ")
        
        if redo == "Y":
            continue
        elif redo == "N":
            print(f"The sum of the numbers you generated is {add_rand_num}! ")
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either Y for YES or N for NO")

randnum()
```

Comment: I was not clear though, what is purpose of generating 10 random numbers, they are not added in the list.

Comment: I saw a wallet miner scam on tiktok and wanted to recreate it and add some more features to it (i wouldn't actually scam but thought it would be fun to do). This code is a 'simplified' version of the code, although I can send you the real code if you want me to. Also thanks for the help, I added an fsum when "add_rand_num" gets printed out so it adds the values together.